# close wizard after clicking button in odoo 12

Tags: python-3.x, odoo, odoo-12

can you please help me regarding close wizard.
i have created a wizard from xml when i add dates and click on xlsx button,

xlsx generated and wizard close it self. it works fine.

 but when i click on pdf, pdf generate successfully but wizard remains open.

 how can i close it.

here is my code of xml.

```
<record id="payment_invoice_wizard_form" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">Invoice Payment Report</field>
        <field name="model">invoice.payment_report</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <form string="Invoice Payment Report">
                <group>
                    <field name="start_date"/>
                    <field name="end_date"/>
                    <field name="status"/>
                </group>
                <!-- other fields -->
                 <footer>
                    <button name="print_pdf" string="Print" type="object" class="btn-primary"/>
                    <button name="print_xls" string="Print in XLS" type="object" class="btn-primary"/>
                    <button string="Cancel" class="btn-default" special="cancel" />   
                </footer>

            </form>          
        </field>
    </record>
```

on py side i am getting all necessary data and returning this function

```
    @api.multi
    def print_pdf(self):
        #mycode
        return self.env.ref('customer_products.pdf_products').report_action(self)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When Odoo [launch the download action of a report](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/12.0/addons/web/static/src/js/chrome/action_manager_report.js#L82) it will check if `close_on_report_download` action attribute is set to `true`, if so it will return action of type `ir.actions.act_window_close` which will close the wizard.

```
@api.multi
def print_pdf(self):
    action = self.env.ref('customer_products.pdf_products').report_action(self)
    action.update({'close_on_report_download': True})
    return action
```

***Edit:***

You can implement the same logic, override [QWEBActionManager](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/11.0/addons/web/static/src/js/report/qwebactionmanager.js#L70) and check if the option is passed through the action definition and if yes close the window.

```
var ActionManager = require('web.ActionManager');
var session = require('web.session');

ActionManager.include({
    ir_actions_report: function (action, options) {
        var self = this;
        return $.when(this._super.apply(this, arguments), session.is_bound).then(function() {
            if (action && action.report_type === 'qweb-pdf' && action.close_on_report_download) {
                return self.do_action({ type: 'ir.actions.act_window_close' });
            }
        });
    },
});
```

Comment: this worked fine for odoo version 12 and 13. but this does not works for odoo 11, can you please tell me what is the replacement for action.update({'close_on_report_download': True}) or other alternatives. thanks

Comment: The option is not available on Odoo 11 and I did not find a similar option. Check my edit.

Comment: yeah thanks for this one it is really helpful, i have checked JS too but did not find this return statement anywhere .. and, i did not find solution too, i had to use an alternative. i raised UserError instead that says to the user to please reopen the wizard.